# Is there an adjective meaning "having the same name as another work"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there an adjective to describe a work that has the same name as another work?  The two works in question may or may not be related.

For instance, instead of writing

> The movie *The Nutty Judge* is based on William Shakespeare's play **of the same title**.

I would like to write something like:

> The movie *The Nutty Judge* is based on William Shakespeare's **same-titled** play.

The adjective "homonymous" is roughly correct but I haven't seen this used in real life.  (I have seen "eponymous" being used erroneously in this context, though.)

Comment: I may well be wrong, but if something is EPONYMOUS it means named after a person. So "William Shakespears King Lear's eponymous TV series." would mean the TV series is named William Shakespear. Not King Lear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with homonymous. It's often used in such contexts.

homonymous, adj. - having the same designation http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homonymous

[**Based on Bernard Shaw's homonymous play, the film dilutes much of its social critique, but retains a moral structure where...**](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=oNCB4oAS_ccC&pg=PA136&lpg=PA136&dq=based+on+Shaw's+homonymous+play&source=bl&ots=9pocf6NoUO&sig=B8K27MmCJVzps6ltM4QdG0y6WZA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vcg5VJXnDpSNNpK9gRg&ved=0CB0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=based%20on%20Shaw's%20homonymous%20play&f=false)

Answer (score 5):

Besides your own suggestion of *homonymous,* you could try *similarly titled* or *identically titled*, depending on the degree of overlap in the respective titles. (You'll find plenty of corroboration for those usages if you run Google searches on them.)